# Best approach for adding IMAP Folder listeners from JavaMail API

Tags: jakarta-mail

Hi I have an IMAP client implemented by javamail API. In javamail, for each open folder, it opens a http connection to the IMAPserver (In my case Gmail). My problem is, when I add mailCountListener for each folder, then all folders need to be kept open which will result in multiple live connections to the IMAPServer. So most of the time I get 'too many simultaneous connections' error from the IMAPserver. Please clarify the best approach for keeping listeners for IMAPFolders. Thanks in advanced.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The listeners require the connections to be open.  If you can't afford that many open connections, you might as well get rid of the listeners and go to a polling model where you open the folder periodically, check for new mail, and close it when you're done.